# Recurrence equations with 2 or more recursive calls

Tags: recurrence-relations

How can I solve the following recurrence equation?
Is there a general approach to solve rec. equation with more recursive calls?

$$A(n) = 2A(n-1) + A(n-5)$$

$$A(0) = 1 , A(1) = 2,A(2) = 4, A(3) = 8, A(4) = 16$$

When i try to use methods from more simple equations with just one recursive part, (like repeated substitution) i end up having just chaos and i don't really see how to apply the basecase then. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: the solution Looks strange

Comment: You don't have $A(2)$ ? Could it be 4?

Comment: of course thanks

Answer (score 5):

The first step is to solve the equation *without* taking the initial conditions into account. We do that by assuming that the solution is of the form $A(n) = r^n$. We get
$$
A(n) = 2A(n-1) + A(n-5)\\
r^n = 2r^{n-1} + r^{n-5}\\
r^5 = 2r^4 + 1
$$
which has the [five solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E5+-+2x%5E4+-+1+%3D+0)
$$
r_1 \approx 2.05597\\
r_2 \approx -0.582170-0.526390 i\\
r_3 \approx -0.582170+0.526390 i\\
r_4 \approx 0.554186-0.694593 i\\
r_5 \approx 0.554186+0.694593 i
$$
(Yes, four of them are complex. That makes little difference.) The trick now is to recognize that setting the sequence to be *any* linear combination of these, like so:
$$
A(n) = a_1r_1^n + a_2r_2^n + a_3r_3^n + a_4r_4^n + a_5r_5^n
$$
also solves the recurrence relation. What is left is to figure out what $a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4, a_5$ should be, and for that, we need the initial conditions. We get the set of equations
$$
\cases{A(0) = 1\\A(1) = 2\\A(2) = 4\\A(3) = 8\\A(4) = 16} \implies\cases{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5= 1\\a_1r_1 + a_2r_2 + a_3r_3 + a_4r_4 + a_5r_5= 2\\a_1r_1^2 + a_2r_2^2 + a_3r_3^2 + a_4r_4^2 + a_5r_5^2= 4\\a_1r_1^3 + a_2r_2^3 + a_3r_3^3 + a_4r_4^3 + a_5r_5^3= 8\\a_1r_1^4 + a_2r_2^4 + a_3r_3^4 + a_4r_4^4 + a_5r_5^4= 16}
$$
which is not really difficult to solve, although the work load is huge unless you have computers to help you.

Comment: Thank's a lot! I was not searching in the right direction.

Comment: @user3637211 I have fixed my answer. It should be correct now.

Comment: thats nice way of solving recursive functions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Generating Functions, and this is what I've come up with.

$A(n)$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$\frac{1}{1-2x-x^5}$$
Wolfram Alpha gives the power series of the above function as:

$$1 + 2 x + 4 x^2 + 8 x^3 + 16 x^4 + 33 x^5 + 68 x^6 + 140 x^7 + 
 288 x^8 + 592 x^9 + 1217 x^{10} + \dots $$

So the first few terms are:
$A(1)=2$, $A(2)=4$, $A(3)=8$, $A(4)=16$, $A(5)=33$, $A(6)=68$, $A(7)=140$, $A(8)=288$ and so on.

Note: The method is not so satisfactory since all you get in the end is a power series and no closed form. That's why I didn't show the method.

Comment: How would you go about encoding the initial conditions into the generating function?

Comment: @Arthur Well, the generating function in general takes the form $f(x) = c_0 +c_1x +c_2x^2 + \dots = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_i x^i$, where $A(n)$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in this function, that is, $A(n) = c_n$. Because $A(0), A(1), A(2), \dots$ are given, we have $c_0 = 1, c_1 = 2, c_2 = 4, \dots c_4 = 16$

Comment: So the fact that the denominator is a reverse of the characteristic polynomial is a coincidence?

Comment: @Arthur Not really. The initial conditions are nice in the sense that they *mostly* satisfy the recurrence if all $A(i)$ with $i<0$ are assumed to be $0$. So all that remains while calculating the generating function is $1$ on the right hand side, and a polynomial on the left.

While in your approach, to go from $A(n)$ to $A(n-1)$ you have to divide by $r$ (from $r^5$ to $r^4$), I have to multiply be $x$ so as to shift the coefficients of the generating function one place to the right.
If your characteristic polynomial were to be $2x^2-x-1$ my generating function would be $\frac{1}{-x^2-x+2}$.